# jQuery disable and enable scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll

```
$('.news-wrap').mouseenter(function(event) {
    $(window).mousewheel(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Window scrolling is disabled, each I leave the element.
How can I enable scrolling with mouseleave event?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?

```
$('#abs').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    var scrollTo = null;
    if (e.type == 'mousewheel') {
        scrollTo = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1);
    } else if (e.type == 'DOMMouseScroll') {
        scrollTo = 1000 * e.originalEvent.detail;
    }

    if (scrollTo) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).scrollTop(scrollTo + $(this).scrollTop());
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 9):

I've written a jQuery plugin to handle this: **[$.disablescroll](https://github.com/ultrapasty/jquery-disablescroll)**.

It stops scrolling from mousewheel, touchmove, and buttons such as <kbd>Page Down</kbd>.

```
$('.news-wrap').mouseenter(function() {

    $(window).disablescroll();

}).mouseleave(function() {

    $(window).disablescroll("undo");

});
```

Hope someone finds this helpful.

Comment: When I was dragging elements up or down and reached the scrollpoint of window, the mouse and draggable element were uncoupling. I tried this plugin and it worked like a charm...nice plugin

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using a plugin on bootstrap tour and the goal was to
Disable scroll when clicking a link and enable it when you clicked an
'end tour' button in the tour.

In HTML create the `div` link by an `id`:

```
<div id='placeholder'><a href='#'>Placeholder link</a> </div>
```

Instantiate jquery with a click function.

start jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*click Function*/
    $('#placeholder').click(function(){
        /*Disables scrolling*/
        $('body').css('scroll', function(){
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
        });
    });  
});
```

Plugin option bootstrap tour when you end the popover:

```
/*This fire when clicking End Tour & placeholder would only work if that what you named the tour.*/
onEnd: function(placeholder) {
    /*Enable scroling*/
    $('body').css({ 'overflow': 'scroll' });
    $(document).off('scroll');
}
```

Comment: It's /*comment*/ instead of just *comment* in JavaScript ;)